# How to kill a unresponsive program from terminal?

Tags: process, video-player

On Ubuntu 12.04 the default Movie Player has hanged on a frame while playing a (faulty?) mkv video. I tried to close it by right click > close but could not terminate it. It also does not start when I try to play a new video.

How can I kill the process from command line?

Comment: 'xkill' in command line works for me well enough. After executing command, cursor turns into an 'X', then click the window for the Movie Player instance you want to kill.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
pkill totem
```

A generally helpful thing to find which processes are hogging the CPU is `top`:
[image: top screenshot]
then you can press <kbd>k</kbd> and type in the `PID` of the process, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to kill it;

Another program that can do this is `htop`:
[image: htop screenshot]
This can also system resources being used, and processes can be killed by selecting them, pressing <kbd>k</kbd>, and then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Parent processes can also be found by pressing <kbd>t</kbd> to toggle tree view.

Comment: bash: kill: totem: arguments must be process or job IDs. But pkill worked. please edit your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Easiest method:

```
killall totem
```

As is says: this will kill -all- instances named totem.

Alternative:

```
ps -ef |grep totem
rinzwind  3601  2236 14 21:05 ?        00:00:00 totem
```

and then kill the process

```
kill -9 3601
```

If totem is started as another user you will need `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `pstree -ps` command to get a complete (tree-)list of running processes with sub-processes, like this:

```
    ├─mission-control(1689)  
    ├─modem-manager(912)  
    ├─mpd(1908)─┬─{mpd}(1909)  
    │           ├─{mpd}(1910)  
    │           ├─{mpd}(1911)  
    │           ├─{mpd}(1912)  
    │           └─{mpd}(1913)  
    ├─nmbd(1858)  
    ├─obex-data-serve(1652)
```

Then use terminals' search function <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to seek out the process in question, for instance; `mpd` followed by this command:

```
kill -9 1908
```